# Yum in Amazon Linux 2 still asks for GPG key even after "rpm --import" when adding Kubernetes repo

Tags: yum, rpm, gpg, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I'm trying to add a *kubernetes* repo to my *Amazon Linux 2* instance and struggle with automatically adding GPG keys.

This is my `/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo`...

```
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

I then try to import the GPG keys:

```
~ # wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg \
         https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg

~ # rpm --import *.gpg
```

However when I run any `yum` command it still doesn't know the keys:

```
# yum upgrade -y
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
kubernetes/signature                                                                                                                                                                                                   |  454 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Importing GPG key 0xA7317B0F:
 Userid     : "Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com>"
 Fingerprint: d0bc 747f d8ca f711 7500 d6fa 3746 c208 a731 7b0f
 From       : https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
kubernetes/signature                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes
Trying other mirror.
No packages marked for update
```

Even if I try to accept them manually it still doesn't work.

```
# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
kubernetes/signature                                                                                                                                                                                                   |  454 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Importing GPG key 0xA7317B0F:
 Userid     : "Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com>"
 Fingerprint: d0bc 747f d8ca f711 7500 d6fa 3746 c208 a731 7b0f
 From       : https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Is this ok [y/N]: y              <<<<< Yes, I accept it!
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
kubernetes/signature                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.4 kB  00:00:01 !!! 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes
Trying other mirror.
No packages marked for update
```

How can I add the key so that YUM accepts it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60134).
Work around it by disabling GPG checks: set `repo_gpgcheck=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo`.

Credits to [drakedevel](https://github.com/drakedevel), who writes:

> I think this is due to Amazon Linux 2 shipping an old version of GnuPG, and something about the repomd.xml.asc signature requires a newer version.
>
> GnuPG 2.0.22 outright rejects the signature on the repository metadata with assuming bad signature from key BA07F4FB due to an unknown critical bit. I haven't been able to figure out what critical bit it's referring to -- there don't appear to be any on the signature or key -- but whatever GnuPG 2.0.22 is upset about is most likely the root cause.
>
> This only affects the repomd signature, so there's zero reason to disable gpgcheck as several others have suggested. Disabling repo_gpgcheck is sufficient and preserves package signature verification (although it's still not an ideal workaround...)